# Daf Yomi Challenge?

Tags: discussion, questions, daf-yomi

Is anyone up for a Daf Yomi Challenge, in which we encourage each other to learn Daf Yomi by posting a question from the Daf (nearly) each day?

**UPDATE**

I appear to be the only one trying to do this. Does anyone else want to participate? I unfortunately do not have the ability to post (nearly) every day.

Comment: why not? ............

Comment: [tag:day-yomi-challenge]

Comment: @doubleaa Correction: [daf-yomi-challenge](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daf-yomi-challenge)

Comment: SethJ, @DoubleAA, [no, we shouldn't be using tags that describe the purpose of the question, or the like, on the question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). (Hence our never using weekly-topic-challenger on those question on the main site.) I am in fact taking the liberty now of detagging all the questions so tagged. That said, +1, great idea.

Comment: @msh210 you don't want to be able to group the questions?

Comment: @SethJ, we group them by _maseches_ anyway. We can have _perek_ tags instead if there are enough questions on a given _perek_. But I'm afraid meta tags are explicitly discouraged by SE: see the page linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: @msh210 I saw that, but what about [tag:mi-yodeya-series]? The point of the tag (as I see it) is to group them to enable followers to have a frame of reference and know that this is part of the challenge.

Comment: @SethJ, good point. We should probably get rid of the mi-yodeya-series tag, too: but it's kinda grandfathered in, no? What I did for the weekly topic challenge (see how well that worked!) is to comment on each topical question that it's for the weekly topic challenge and link to the meta post in the topic. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @msh210 I guess that would work if you click the title link and read the question. My goal was for someone following to log on, see the tag and easily identify the question as part of the series/challenge (something that's unnecessary for the MiYodeya series). Not to mention searches on the site, sorting by tag.

Comment: @SethJ, for searches by tag, perhaps _perek_ tags, as I suggested above. For spotting such questions, the same solutions works, though not as well as the tag proposed above. But I don't think we have much of a choice: that blog post is pretty explicit and vehement. Do you disagree?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4383/discussion-between-seth-j-and-msh210)

Comment: We can also create a post on meta for each masechet and link the questions in an answer, like for the weekly challenges.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, you mean, listed by _daf_? Sounds like a good idea, if someone implements it. Alternatively, maybe we should have daf-2, daf-3, daf-4, ..., daf-176 tags. (I'm *mostly* kidding.)

Comment: @msh210 I do like the idea of linking back here in the question, and I like the idea of creating answers (here) by Masechta with links to the questions. However, all together it does seem like a lot of work for the same effect of just a simple tag, not to mention that the tag will have an added SEO benefit.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, ping (I like your idea).

Comment: @MonicaCellio It seems your idea is generating enough discussion here in comment-land to bring it out as an answer and let the whole community vote and discuss.

Comment: SethJ Do you mind if I write up a collection meta post for Brachot today?

Comment: @DoubleAA, not at all. I wish I had more time to contribute more questions. I also wish more people were participating. But go right ahead - maybe it will spur more interest.

Answer (score 3):

I like the idea.  We could implement it by creating a question on meta for each masechet and collecting links to the questions in a CW answer, like we do for the weekly challenges.  The links would ideally be ordered by, and annotated with, the daf.

I don't think we should create a special tag.  Each qurstion will already be tagged by masechet and linked on meta; that should be sufficient indexing, and SE frowns on meta tags.