# Daf Yomi Challenge Poll

Tags: discussion, daf-yomi

I'm not sure if this is appropriate, so Mods, feel free to close it if it's not, but can we please take a poll of who is participating in Daf Yomi and would like to take turns providing questions for the [**Daf Yomi Challenge**](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1325/5)?

I think the best way to take the pulse of the community would be to seek both positive **and negative** responses.

So please **upvote this question** if you are participating in Daf Yomi generally (if virtually nobody upvotes, I'll have a pretty clear idea that this challenge is not gaining any traction).

*Upvote the first comment on this question* if you are not participating in Daf Yomi generally.

***Answer this question*** if you are interested in actively participating in the [**Daf Yomi Challenge**](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1325/5) by taking turns asking interesting questions spurred by your learning.

PLEASE DON'T DOWNVOTE THIS QUESTION. It will only throw off the mechanism of judging the number of actual people participating, and the purpose of this poll is not to gauge the popularity of the idea but to gauge the potential to implement it.

Comment: Upvote this comment if you are *not* participating in Daf Yomi generally.

Comment: Oy. This is not looking promising.

Answer (score 1):

I am willing to try.  I don't study the full daf every day, but I do some days and I read summaries the rest of the time.  So I'm not really "doing" daf yomi in the sense you mean, but I'm encountering the material and am willing to try harder to generate questions from that.

One challenge is that a question on daf X will quite possibly be addressed on daf X+3, so there is likely to be some lag because I don't want to ask easily-resolved questions of the "just keep reading" style.

Comment: (Re: your second paragraph) Fair enough, and that was msh210's initial concern with the challenge, but as you may have noticed, I've posted some questions on the periphery of the subject matter, which I think is legitimate.

Comment: Heh.  Community bumped this question on the very day that I encountered a question, *did* read ahead, and still [asked a daf question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33333/472). :-)

Comment: There are no coincidences! :-)